# Why is using a for loop faster than apply, in computing the norm of all rows/columns of a matrix?

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, purrr

Consider the following

```
n <- 10^4
p <- 2
foo <- matrix(runif(p*n), n, p)
```

I would like to compute the norm of each row of the matrix, i.e., to compute `sqrt(crossprod(a_i))` where `a_i` is the i-th row of `foo`. I can do this with `apply`, or with a `for` loop:

```
for_loop <- function(x){
  range <- seq_along(x[,1])
  foo <- range
  for (i in range){
    foo[i] <- sqrt(crossprod(x[i,]))
    }
  foo
}

use_apply <- function(x){
  apply(x, 1, function(r) sqrt(crossprod(r)))
}
```

I thought the simpler `apply` code would be faster, however:

```
> microbenchmark(for_loop(foo), use_apply(foo), times = 1000)
Unit: milliseconds
           expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
  for_loop(foo) 16.07111 18.87690 24.25369 20.78997 27.66441 179.8374  1000
 use_apply(foo) 24.77948 29.05891 35.98689 31.89625 40.30085 205.1632  1000
```

note that `times = 1000` can take quite a bit of time, if you don't have a fast machine you may want to use `microbenchmark` defaults. Why is `apply` slower than the `for` loop code? Is there some function from `purrr` which would be faster?

**EDIT** I couldn't believe that `crossprod(x)` would be so much slower than `sum(x*x)`, so I wanted to check Emmanuel-Lin's results. I get very different timings:

```
my_loop <- function(x){
  range <- seq_along(x[,1])
  foo <- range
  for (i in range){
    foo[i] <- sqrt(sum((x[i,] *x[i,])))
    }
  foo
}

my_apply <- function(x){
  apply(x, 1, function(r) sqrt(sum(r*r)))
}

for_loop <- function(x){
  range <- seq_along(x[,1])
  foo <- range
  for (i in range){
    foo[i] <- sqrt(crossprod(x[i,]))
  }
  foo
}

use_apply <- function(x){
  apply(x, 1, function(r) sqrt(crossprod(r)))
}
> microbenchmark(for_loop(foo), my_loop(foo), use_apply(foo), my_apply(foo))
Unit: milliseconds
           expr       min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
  for_loop(foo) 16.299758 17.77176 21.59988 19.04428 22.44558 131.33819   100
   my_loop(foo)  9.950813 12.02106 14.43540 12.66142 15.26865  45.42030   100
 use_apply(foo) 25.480019 27.95396 31.98351 29.85244 36.41599  60.88678   100
  my_apply(foo) 13.277354 14.98329 17.60356 15.98103 19.70325  34.07097   100
```

ok, `my_apply` and `my_loop` are faster (I still can't believe it! What, is `crossprod` optimized for slowness? :-/) but **not so faster** as Emmanuel-lin found. It's probably related to some dimension congruence checks which `crossprod` performs.

Comment: Why did you think the apply would be faster? If you properly pre-allocate memory, for loops are almost always faster in R. This myth that for loops in R are slow is a lie.

Comment: @MrFlick it looks like `apply` can't be faster than a `for` loop, since **it's** a `for` loop. However, according to LyzandeR, other `*apply` functions should be faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apply` is literally an R for-loop if you check the code:

```
   #only the for-loop code shown here
   if (length(d.call) < 2L) {
        if (length(dn.call)) 
            dimnames(newX) <- c(dn.call, list(NULL))
        for (i in 1L:d2) {
            tmp <- forceAndCall(1, FUN, newX[, i], ...)
            if (!is.null(tmp)) 
                ans[[i]] <- tmp
        }
    }
    else for (i in 1L:d2) {
        tmp <- forceAndCall(1, FUN, array(newX[, i], d.call, 
            dn.call), ...)
        if (!is.null(tmp)) 
            ans[[i]] <- tmp
    }
```

In addition to the above, `apply` will run a series of checks too, to make sure the arguments you provided were correct. It is the above that make it a bit slower.

However, `lapply`, `sapply` and `vapply` are C-based for-loops and therefore much faster than an R-based for loop.

Comment: Do you really have examples where the `*apply` functions are faster than a for loop? Most of the time people are just sloppy with memory allocations which slow for loops down. Most of the time for loops can be faster than sapply if you properly pre-allocate.

Comment: @MrFlick Too big for a comment but here you go:  `microbenchmark(
 forloop = {vec <- numeric(1000)
 for (i in 1:length(vec)) {
  
  vec[i] <- i * 2
  
 }},
 sapply = sapply(1:1000, function(x) x * 2)
)` By the way if there is a way to make an R-base for-loop faster than the `*apply` functions, do post an answer. this is what stackoverflow is all about. Learning from others.

Comment: @LyzandeR is there a way to apply one of the other functions you mentioned, which you say use C-loop and thus are faster,  to my use case? i.e., can I compute the norm of each row of `foo` using one of `lapply`, `sapply`, `vapply`?

Comment: @DeltaIV since you are doing non-trivial calculations inside the loop, the relative difference between `for` and `sapply` will be very small. It's true that the C-based for loop is faster than the R-based for loop, but even the R-based loop is fast relative to the code run within each iteration.

Comment: @LyzandeR that it a good example. Of course it would be even better to just use `vec<-vec*2` in that case. I should have clarified that I've never seen a non-trival example where that's true. But your counterpoint does give one hope that one might exist.

Comment: @DeltaIV your data is in a matrix, so `apply` is a good function to use to iterate rows. Another option would be to split your matrix per row and then use `lapply` but I doubt you will see a huge difference in speed as Gregor mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

To complete @LyzandeR answer on RAM.

You can perform computation way faster by coding your self the multiplication:

Repalce crossprod by `sum(r * r)`

```
my_loop <- function(x){
  range <- seq_along(x[,1])
  foo <- range
  for (i in range){
    foo[i] <- sqrt(sum(x[i,] * x[i,]))
  }
  foo
}


my_sapply <- function(x){
  apply(x, 1, function(r) sqrt(sum(r * r)))
}

microbenchmark(for_loop(X), 
               use_apply(X),
               my_loop(X),
               my_sapply(X),
               times = 100)
```

And the results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
         expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
  for_loop(X) 122.45210 145.67150 179.84469 177.63446 199.10468 460.73182   100
 use_apply(X) 141.99250 169.11596 198.82019 198.11953 223.50906 296.94566   100
   my_loop(X)  10.38776  11.61263  16.47609  14.24066  19.07957  58.50008   100
 my_sapply(X)  13.21431  15.32081  23.23124  18.39573  26.08099 222.57685   100
```

So it is more than 10 times faster!

Also you can notice than your machine is way faster than mine :/

Comment: nice! But please also see my comment to @LyzandeR. Ps this is actually my slowest machine ;-) I have another one which is twice as fast, and should get an even faster one in January... though the new one will be a Mac, so I don't know how R on Mac compares to R on Windows.

Comment: hmmm, something very, very weird is happening here. Read my edited question: I cannot confirm your timings.